# php-fpm on ubuntu 20.04 with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I have installed nginx on ubuntu 20.04 server. Simple HTML sites are working fine. Later i decided to install `php-fpm`. I have phpinfo.php file in my `/var/www/html` folder with following code

```
<?php
phpinfo ();
?>
```

Now when i point to this file in my browser my browser downloads phpinfo.php file instead of showing me my PHP information page. I believe my PHP is not working or my nginx is not using or passing my request through PHP. I also believe that there is something i'm missing in default file sitting in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` folder. This missing part is suppose to use installed php on this server. My nginx.conf file is:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        gzip on;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My default file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` is

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_name_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your nginx config?

Comment: Your `default` file is missing this block for forwarding nginx req to php-fpm: `location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }`  Please adjust the php version here with php-fpm version you have installed.

Comment: Instead of comment can you please answer with final look of my default file. This will show exactly where your suggested code will go in default file. Thank you.